# Cannot copy one table to another?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am using python to copy one table (dictionary) to another (origin_dictionary) in SQLite, and here is my code to this part:

```
    def copyDictionaryToOrigin(self):
    dropTableQueryStr = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS origin_dictionary"
    createTableQueryStr = "CREATE TABLE origin_dictionary (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, word TEXT, type TEXT)"
    syncTableQueryStr = "INSERT INTO origin_dictionary (word, type) SELECT word, type FROM dictionary"

    self.cur.execute(dropTableQueryStr)
    self.cur.fetchone()

    self.cur.execute(createTableQueryStr)
    result = self.cur.fetchone()

    self.cur.execute(syncTableQueryStr)
    result = self.cur.fetchone()
```

With running this code, I can see a origin_dictionary table is created, but there is no data in the table. I could not find out the reason why the data didn't copy over to the new table. can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Is there any data in the dictionary table?

Comment: yes there is data in the dictionary table. actually I can run the copy command successfully from sqlite shell, but it does not work in python code

Comment: Are you committing the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to simply copy one table to another, why don't you use `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`? Also, you need to `commit()` your statements.

Simply use code below, and it should work:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(example.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS origin_dictionary")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE origin_dictionary AS SELECT * FROM dictionary")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```